# ViewController in other file

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm a novice with Swift 2. I tried to create a UIAlertController in another file.

This is my code :

```
class my_view_error: UIViewController {

func my_error(my_title: String, my_message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: my_title, message: my_message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
    } 
}
```

I'm receiving a compile time error:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

My question is, is it possible to create a ViewController in a file other than `ViewController.swift`?

Answer (score 0):

You created a `UIViewController` subclass called `my_view_error`. The `UIViewController` method `presentViewController` expects `self` (a `my_view_error`) to be on the screen at the time the method is called.

Your `my_error` function is perfectly fine, but it should be moved to a view controller that is actually on the screen. There is no need to create a `UIViewController` just to present a `UIAlertController`. In fact, `UIAlertController` *is* a `UIViewController`, and does not need help from a custom view controller.

Just like with any view controller, the view controller that is presenting the alert must be on the screen in order to perform the presentation.

Each view controller may have its own `.swift` file. There is no need to create one for a `UIAlertController`, however.

Heres a version of the function that uses `rootViewController` on `UIApplication` to get the currently on-screen view controller, and then uses that to present your alert:

```
func my_error(my_title: String, my_message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: my_title, message: my_message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    // Uses UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController! instead of self
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
}
```

Comment: Ok , thank you for your information, so i moved my function "my_error" to my view_controller , it's works but if i want call this function in other file , the function is not recognized "use of unresolved identifier 'my_error' , i have to create a second ViewController ?

Comment: @Guillaume No, if you are trying to call `my_error` from another class then you would have to get the instance of your view controller in order to call the method.

Comment: I added a version of your method that will use the current on screen view controller.